# Spring JpaRepository dows not execute delete or insert statements after select

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a very strange problem. I have a Spring Boot application with a JpaRepository and hibernate to handle persisting simple Java objects. These only have a number of string properties. No Relationships, no special subclasses, very very simple.  I am using the Spring Boot 2.3.7.Release. I tested this effect both with an H2-Database as well as PostegreSQL. Done this hundreds of times before.

On my development notebook running on windows 10, everything works as expected - I can save entities, delete them. But when I try to deploy the application on my linux server (centOS), the delete and insert statements are simply not executed.

For example, if I call the save function, I would expect first a select statement (to check, if the entry is already present), followed by insert (as it is not in my case). And that's exactly what I see on my notebook. On the server I see the initial select statement is executed, but the following insert is not. It is not even tried.

The same holds true for deleteAll() - I see the select statement, but the following delete statements are missing. And I do not get any error message. Nothing. Hibernate is just omitting the delete and insert statements.

I can insert data into the database manually with the same user used in my application and the program even does pick the saved data up - I can retrieve them and display them. So the connection to the database works, the mapping works, it's just as if hibernate is in some kind of read-only mode, omitting all delete and insert statements.

Any idea about that? I already checked all available configurations (that are the same, besides some environment variables, which only provide the passwords).

I am simply running out of ideas where to look. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Time to debug ...

Comment: I did a full debug - it looks completely similar, only the insert and delete statements are missing on the linus server

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution - another datasource was autoconfigured by a part of the application (spring batch) and it was a race between the two, which one got initialized first. On my Laptop the postgres jpa won resulting in a working system, on the server, the other one worked, resulting in the problems.

The only difference I found in the debug log was a longer time for the JPA initialization...

After manually connecting Spring batch to the postgresql, it works.